# Ultra-efficient compression

Tags: log-files, compression

I store a very large (TBytes) amount of logs. These logs will rarely be extracted, and when they will - only a single file will be required.

Could you recommend an ultra-efficient and extremely stable compression algorithm that's [considerably better than bzip2](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/log.php)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

lzma (aka xz) should do notably better than bzip2, but will take a bit longer.
paq (aka zp) will do quite a bit better yet, but will take ages to compress and just as long to decompress.

Both are available for Windows and *nix environments (most *nix systems have packages 
available)

A quick test on a smartd log:

```
Original       3900K
GZip            208K    0.11s
BZip2            71K    3.07s
XZ               13K    1.76s*
ZP                6K   25.68s*
```

*I've got -O3 compiled ports for `xz` and `zp`. The `gzip` and `bzip2` binaries were precompiled with no optimization.

Comment: See also http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/log.php

Comment: xz is faster than bz2. Even if your quick test shows it.

Comment: In linux lzma is also supported by `tar` http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Compression.html

Comment: @Brendan, just tested `-Os` compiled versions of `xz` and `bzip2` on 100MB of random data. bzip2 took 45.39s while `xz` took 1:25.77; bzip2 should be faster for any sizable dataset and similar compiler optimizations. @leonbloy, tar also supports the use of external compressors if they can work on stdin to stdout, which all of these compressors do.

Comment: @ChrisS but the original 7z doesn't, also a built in alias of `-J` sure gives *something*

Comment: @HubertKario The original 7z doesn't what?? Alias what??

Comment: @ChrisS Original 7zip can't work on standard input and standard output. Also, the fact, you can easily use xz compression just by adding `-J` to `tar` instead of `-j` or `-z` sure is handy, no?